# Dialog box positioning in multi-zone layout in Angular/Bootstrap-4

Tags: css, angular, typescript, bootstrap-4, modal-dialog

I have been working on angular app which contains multi layout i.e sidebar and main layout. I want to position my dialog box in main layout but it is displaying on top of total layout.

How to display it on only middle of main layout.

[image]

[image]

Comment: the answer below worked for you?

Answer (score 0):

The reason the modal (or dialog box) is covering the whole view is because the `.modal` class uses a `position:fixed` with similar margins to both sides (via margin:auto) and a fixed `max-width` defined.

You didn't share your code, so I created a sidebar which would occupy 20% of the screen width; this means that the remaining 80% will our 'main layout'. Now to ensure that the modal is strictly within the confines of the 'main layout', we added a margin-left of 20% (which is exactly the width we have assigned to the sidebar);

relevant **CSS**:

```
  .sideBar{width:20vw; background:lightblue; height:100vh;}
  .mainArea{ width:80vw; height:100vh;}
  ::ng-deep .modal{margin-left:20vw;}
```

relevant **HTML**:

```
<div class='row'>
    <div class='sideBar'>
    </div>
    <div class='mainArea'>
        <ng-template #content let-modal>
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="modal-basic-title">Profile update</h4>
                <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="modal.dismiss('Cross click')">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <form>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="dateOfBirth">Date of birth</label>
        <div class="input-group">
          <input id="dateOfBirth" class="form-control" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd" name="dp" ngbDatepicker #dp="ngbDatepicker">
          <div class="input-group-append">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary calendar" (click)="dp.toggle()" type="button"></button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark" (click)="modal.close('Save click')">Save</button>
  </div>
</ng-template>

<button class="btn btn-lg btn-outline-primary" (click)="open(content)">Launch demo modal</button>

<hr>

<pre>{{closeResult}}</pre>
    </div>
</div>
```

complete working [stackblitz available here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-b4hqcr)